# How to convert "normal" coordinates to OSM coordinates in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am quite new to OpenLayers, and already stuck on my first problem. I am trying to convert "normal" coordinates, which I copied from Google Maps to OSM ones to center my map to a certain area.
Now as far as i understood ist the "normal" coordinate system EPSG:4326 and the OSM one is EPSG:3857 or EPSG:900913, which is the same. so my Javascript code is:

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(53.537460, 9.953227).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857")), 5);
```

But this centers to a total different location. what am I missing?

Comment: Does it center correctly if you leave the transformation bit out?

Comment: No, it solves to another ("wrong") location

Comment: And where does it suppose to set the center?

Comment: I'm not sure I would use the term normal. 4326 means latitude and longitude (or more correctly, longitude/latitude, as scai has pointed out), while 3857 is spherical mercator, projected in meters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.de/maps?q=53.537460,+9.953227) and [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=53.537460&mlon=9.953227#map=15/53.5375/9.9532) show exactly the same position. Everything else would be odd.

However you are mixing up *lat* and *lon*. `OpenLayers.LonLat()` accepts first *lon*, then *lat* as the name already tells you. But you are passing *lat* first and then *lon*, which will result in a completely different position of course.

Comment: Thanks! you save the day

Answer (score 2):

Is your location in Steinwerder (Hamburger Hafen) or off the Horn of Africa? I assume the first so the Latitude would be 53 degree north and the longitude 9 degree west.

This should set your map in the right location.

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(9.953227,53.537460).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getProjectionObject()), 5);
```

You only need to know the input coordinate reference and use the `getProjectObject` function to get the target reference.